# Merge Statement is causing performance issues in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-merge

I am trying to update using merge statement in oracle and the source has 20M records and the target has 118 M records. The performance of the Merge is taking a very long time. Listed below is my Merge Statement. I have also placed a screenshot of the Explain plan for reference.[image]

```
MERGE
/*+ parallel(A,10) enable_parallel_dml*/
INTO
(
  SELECT
    PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
    AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
    AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
    SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
    SRC_CREATED_DATE,
    SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
  FROM
    EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP
)
A USING
(
  SELECT
    pay_range_start_date_key,
    aa_person_natural_key,
    aa_person_assignment_key,
    schedule_line_id,
    MAX(src_created_date) src_created_date,
    MAX(src_last_update_date) src_last_update_date
  FROM
    edwfin.psp_labor_schd_day_f_rollup_frs_356
  GROUP BY
    pay_range_start_date_key,
    aa_person_natural_key,
    aa_person_assignment_key,
    schedule_line_id
)
B ON
(
  A.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY = B.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY AND
  A.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY    = B.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY AND
  A.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY = B.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY AND
  A.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID         = B.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET
    A.SRC_CREATED_DATE     = B.SRC_CREATED_DATE,
    A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE = B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
  WHERE
    A.SRC_CREATED_DATE      <> B.SRC_CREATED_DATE
  OR A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE <> B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE;
  COMMIT;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @jarlh I am using oracle

Comment: Is it a one time deal or is it a query you often have to execute? Since it is a single query, all updates are executed as a transaction which slows down the whole process. If I had to do it, I would use some code to do it and commit every 1000 updates or so.

Comment: @Tarik No Its just a one time update

Comment: Still, I would code it using a Python script.

Comment: @Tarik we don't have the option to use python

Comment: Python or whatever language.

Comment: Looping iterations with multiple commits, especially using an external script, will ***always*** take longer than a single SQL transaction, potentially by several orders of magnitude. That would force multiple CPU context switches, network i/o (even on localhost), redo log sync operations, and control file updates that wouldn't exist otherwise. You would also lose any logical consistency (what happens if source data changes in mid-process?) in the transaction if you break it up. I don't see any obvious tuning opportunities in your explain plan, unless you made `B` a materialized view.

Comment: My making `B` a materialized view and using that to perform your aggregate calculations, you can break up the processing required into two steps, preserve the logical consistency of your merge, and keep everything as SQL: close to the Oracle kernel without extra CPU context switching.

Comment: @pmdba ok let me try now and update you .

Comment: @pmdba I tried creating Materialized view on b Then gather stats on it and then  used it in merge still the performance issue is persistant .

Comment: @pmdba Is there a different approach to this

Comment: indexing your join columns may help, if you haven't done that already.

Comment: @pmdba already tried that, since it is a large table oracle Optimizer considers full table scan. I have also gathered stats on both the table.

Comment: @Tarik Is there a way where we can use PL/SQL to make this process faster?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one time deal, I would simple recreate the table with a CTAS or Insert... as select... and then add the indexes back afterwards. You are already using parallel execution; the CTAS or Insert ... as select... can be done direct path.

The select statement would look something like this. I am also assuming that all the key columns are defined NOT NULL.

```
select < all columns from A, except SRC_CREATED_DATE and SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE >
    , case 
        when B.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY is null 
          then A.SRC_CREATED_DATE
          else 
            case
              when     A.SRC_CREATED_DATE <> B.SRC_CREATED_DATE OR A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE <> B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE 
                then B.SRC_CREATED_DATE
                else A.SRC_CREATED_DATE
              end
        end SRC_CREATED_DATE
    , case 
        when B.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY is null 
          then A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
          else 
            case
              when     A.SRC_CREATED_DATE <> B.SRC_CREATED_DATE OR A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE <> B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE 
                then B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
                else A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
              end
        end SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
     from EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP  A  
left join (  SELECT
    pay_range_start_date_key,
    aa_person_natural_key,
    aa_person_assignment_key,
    schedule_line_id,
    MAX(src_created_date) src_created_date,
    MAX(src_last_update_date) src_last_update_date
  FROM
    edwfin.psp_labor_schd_day_f_rollup_frs_356
  GROUP BY
    pay_range_start_date_key,
    aa_person_natural_key,
    aa_person_assignment_key,
    schedule_line_id
    ) B
on   A.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY = B.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY AND
     A.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY    = B.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY AND
     A.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY = B.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY AND
     A.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID         = B.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID
```

Comment: But I only have to update the 2 columns SRC_CREATED_DATE and SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE

Comment: can you please advise on how this can be done for the above logic.

Comment: The concept is that you "generate" the data as how it would appear after the update. The concept is that you do a left outer join between A and B using the join keys. You then use the original match conditions in a CASE statement in the projection, to pick either the columns from A or from B.

Comment: A small example code would do a world for good for me , is it possible to use to code above and give me an example

Comment: I'll edit my answer above, with a simple example, since I can format it nicely.

Comment: @karthik A possible but risky way is to execute the query with logging set to off. The risk is to have the database flagged as inconsistent. Otherwise, it's definitely faster.

Comment: @Tarik it is not possible as this has be done in production, Can we Divided the data into smaller files and then update

Comment: Them the best option is a script or program made in any language that will loop through the rows one by one and update them. More reliable, faster and no impact on production.

Comment: @Tarik is there a way you can help me create a script in PL/SQL to handle this issue

Comment: You already have a SQL script to do it. However, the data is so big that doing it in one go is very slow and will probably hang your production system. I do not have Oracle and am not familiar with your system. Maybe writing a stored procedure would do, using loops and commiting every so many rows. But then why doing it in SQL? You need to hire the services of a programmer that have access to your dev system to do the job. It's beyond what Stackoverflow can do for you.

Comment: _"best option is a script or program made in any language that will loop through the rows one by one"_    No.  row-by-row = slow-by-slow.   _"But then why doing it in SQL"_  Maybe because sql is the language by when data is accessed and modified.  Anything else - pl/sql, java, python, etc.  still has to come down to issuing SQL statements for the database to process.

Comment: @karthik. Did you try based on the example I showed?

Comment: @BobC Yes I did, it is still doing a Full table scan and creating hash joins and the query is running for more than 5 hours now, will update you. We are parallelly trying updating by dividing it based on dates

Comment: Before you do that, can you provide an active SQL Monitor report for that execution. Full scans and hash joins is generally what I want to see...